# Using json to pull live crypto prices into my google sheets portfolio

Tags: json, google-sheets

```
    function KrakenPriceFunction(id)
    {
    var url = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair="+id;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var myjson = JSON.parse(json);
    var price = myjson.data.price;
    return price;
    }
    function refreshKrakenPriceFunction(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("KRAKEN");
    var coin=sheet.getRange("B3:B9").getValues();
    var krakenSttRange=3;
    for (i=0; i<=coin.length-1; i++){
    var val=KrakenPriceFunction(coin[i]);
    sheet.getRange("C"+krakenSttRange).setValue(val);
    krakenSttRange=krakenSttRange+1
    }
    }
```

Here is an old script I am using. Haven't used json in years and am finding it difficult to adapt for my needs. Trying to pull live price into my portfolio

Here is the google sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yGBEzc-V5nqSUjQ_UANzVi11RI0T4-Wd3VL7T3G2pFY/edit?usp=sharing

Used an old script I had from kucoin. But doesn't recognize "price"?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand expected result from your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I have a google sheet that shows live price for my crypto. I am trying to pull prices from my Kraken exchange.

Comment: Have you read [Google Script - REST API public endpoints](https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040136292-Google-Script-REST-API-public-endpoints)